# I want to know the total products in my product table but it shows an error , What will be the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to know the total products in my product table but it shows an error. What will be the right syntax?

here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(product_name) FROM product";
$result=mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();
$neeraj =  $row->COUNT(product_name);
echo $neeraj;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the complete error message.

Comment: rename the count in the sql to a name, otherwise "count(product_name)" will be interpreted as a function call, so in the sql use "count(...) AS NAME" and then in PHP use "->NAME"

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Comment section is not meant for answers. If you have a solution please use the Answer space. Comments will be removed.

Comment: @Dharman i'm not sure about my answer, because i've not tested it... if turns out to be right, i will create the answer and let the creator mark that as supposed correct answer

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia This was more of a suggestion for future, because this question has already been answered and is closed as duplicate. In future either flag to close or answer. You can delete an answer if it turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, to get the count you should submit `COUNT(…)` query and get the first column of the result.
So, correct code would be look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(product_name) FROM product";
$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
$neeraj = (int) $result->fetch_row()[0];
echo $neeraj;
```